# How do you set the paint color to orange in Android?

Tags: java, android, colors

In Android, I am able to set Paint Color to some colors, but for orange, I cannot. Does anyone know if there is an option to set Paint Color to Orange?

Here are some examples of setting Paint Color to other colors beside Orange:

```
p.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
p.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
```

etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The orange color has a hex value `#FFA500` or `Color.rgb(255, 165, 0)` so

```
p.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
```

or

```
p.setColor(0xffa500);
```

see [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/orange-color.html) for more options.

Answer (score 2):

You may create your own orange color, like this:

```
int orange = Color.rgb(255, 165, 0);
p.setColor(orange);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`Color` is not an enum, it's a class that contains `Color` constants for the most commonly used colors. You can easily create new custom colors by instantiating `Color`. You can create a new instance of `Color` by passing the red, green, and blue values as floats between 0 and 255. Here's a simple example:

```
Color mycolor = new Color(0, 0, 255);
```

If the color you're making will simply be brighter or darker than the original color, you can use the `brighter` or `darker` methods, like this:

```
Color brigherColor = mycolor.brighter();
```

or this:

```
Color darkerColor = mycolor.darker();
```

For more information, see the [official documentation for `Color`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

Answer (score 1):

I would write this:

```
int ORANGE= 0xffa500;
p.setColor(ORANGE);
```